# Unity C# Rigidbody Duda acerca de funcionamiento de variables y objetos

Tags: c#, unity, rigidbody

soy Facundo.

Contexto: Quiero hacer que un personaje o objeto salte, se como hacerlo pero nose porque lo hace y quisiera saber para tener un mayor entendimiento, muchas gracias.

Mi pregunta:
¿Porque por ej. cuando creo una variable `Rigidbody`  y le asigno el `getComponent<Rigidbody>()` me permite hacer `variable.AddForce()`?

Aclaro, aprendí que una variable es solo un contenedor al que se le deposita un valor, entonces si `variable` solo es un contenedor que en contiene una **COPIA** del valor que le paso, en este caso una copia del `Rigidbody` del objeto, entonces ¿Por qué al modificar la variable esta cambia el valores del `Rigidbody`?¿no se supone que solo contiene el valor que le pasamos y es independiente de este porque solo es una copia no?¿Si es una copia entonces cuando yo le añado la fuerza con `variable.AddForce()` solo debería cambiarse el valor esa variable y no el de mi `Rigibody` porque si quisiera cambiar el del `Rigidbody` tendría que ser `getComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce()`?

Pero es como si no importara y quiero saber porque para mi no parece tener mucha lógica.

Les dejo mi codigo por si lo precisan para contestar, intento ser lo mas claro posible, gracias por leer.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody playerRb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * 500);

        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Aclaro, aprendí que una variable es solo un contenedor al que se le deposita un valor, entonces si variable solo es un contenedor que en contiene una COPIA del valor que le paso, en este caso una copia del Rigidbody del objeto

Además de poder guardar valores como son los String, Integer, Float, ..., también puedes guardar referencias a valores o estructuras/objetos.

En este caso, cuando guardas en una variable el resultado de la función `GetComponent<RigidBody>()` (en este caso siendo aplicada al objeto que contiene el script que has creado), **se obtiene una referencia** al componente RigidBody asociado al objeto.

Ahora a través de esta variable puedes acceder a la información de este RigidBody en cuestión, pero no estás realizando una copia del RigidBody. Es por ello que cuando haces posteriormente `playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * 500);` se aplica dicha función al objeto que contiene este script.

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor pensar en las variables no primitivas(int, bool, float, string) como enlaces directos(como el de tu juego favorito en tu escritorio).
Puedes crear tantos accesos directos como quieras pero solo habrá una carpeta en el que esta tu juego.

```
public class Player : Monobeha....{
     public Rigibdody rb1;
     public Rigibdody rb2;
     public Rigibdody rb3;
     void Start()
     {

         rb1= GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         rb2= GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         rb3= GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

         // al final todas referencian al mismo rigidbody
    
    }
}
```

El metodo GetComponent busca un Rigidbody en el gameObject que este anclado, si no encuentra ninguno devolvera null(sin referencia);